# In which language ABRSM exams are normally taken?

Tags: abrsm

In which language ABRSM exams are taken in countries where the dominant language is not English?

[Swiss ABRSM page](http://ch.abrsm.org/) is all in English, but the dominant language in my Swiss region is German. Can I expect that it will be possible to use German during the music theory exam?

Comment: I'd suggest contacting the board and asking them for a definitive answer. They should be happy to help with queries from potential candidates.

Comment: They do some effort to translate the theory exams in the local languages but I usually don't bother. The main purpose of doing an international music qualification is to get experience in doing music in English

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick phone call revealed that you can take the theory exams in German, if you request it at the time of entry. English and German will appear for the questions, but I suspect it's standard German rather than any Swiss/German.